# IDL program returns erronius results if input is too big

Tags: idl-programming-language

I'm trying to run a large batch of data through my IDL program, but when I do I get nonsensical results.

If I split up the input and then give each piece to the program separately and then stitch the output together it works fine. This has led to to think there is an overflow problem occurring somewhere in the code, but I haven't had any luck debugging it so far.

Is there a way that I can change the default data type size in IDL so that if I declare a variable such as...

```
A = functionCall(blah,blah2)
```

it will initiate the variable as a 32bit value instead of a 16bit (which is the default)?

I know you can do this manually by doing

```
A = long(functionCall(blah,blah2))
```

by my code is a few thousand lines long and I'd rather not go through and manually change this for every variable.

Comment: So are you having a problem with memory or the difference between `integer` and `long integer` variables?  If the latter, then just add the following to your code in the relevant places:  `*1L`.  This will convert things to long integers.  Also, IDL is 64-bit by default, unless you are running a version earlier than 6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is to default to 32-bit integers, you can put a compile_opt statement in your codes. Put

```
compile_opt defint32
```

at the top of your routines.  Or,

```
compile_opt idl2
```

which is shorthand for defint32 and strictarr (enforces using square brackets for indexing).  This will make IDL use 32-bit integers everywhere it would normally have used 16-bit integers.

However, I'm not sure how this addresses your 'large data' problem.  You may want to use

```
help, /mem
```

to check your memory usage.